# When can eta reduction change a function's type?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, pointfree

What exactly is going on with the following?

```
> let test = map show

> :t test
test :: [()] -> [String]

> :t (map show)
(map show) :: Show a => [a] -> [String]
```

I am wondering how I failed to notice this before?  I actually encountered the problem with "map fromIntegral" rather than show - my code doesn't compile with the pointfree form, but works fine without eta reduction.

Is there a simple explanation of when eta reduction can change the meaning of Haskell code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction), which applies when a binding doesn't take parameters and allows the binding to be shareable when it otherwise wouldn't be due to polymorphism, on the theory that if you don't give it a parameter you want to treat it as something "constant"-ish (hence shared).  You can disable it in `ghci` with `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`; this is often useful in `ghci`, where you often intend such expressions to be fully polymorphic.  (In a Haskell source file, make the first line

```
 {-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

instead.)

Comment: WOW I am sorry, should have known.  I had even tried the language pragma but forgotten to include the hash signs, and GHC wasn't saying the usual thing about "probable cause."

Comment: To be precise it's the monomorphism restriction combined with GHCi's extended defaulting rules.